# How do I display some of the pages in the pagination?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Can you tell me how Gatsby can implement a similar pagination (see screenshot)?

Right now I just have the whole array of pages (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Next Page) displayed. And I want to output 1, 2, ..., 5, Next Page

[image: Pagination example]

gatsby-node.js

```js
  const posts = result.data.postsRemark.edges;
  const postsPerPage = 2;
  const numPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage);
  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/blog` : `/blog/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/blog.js'),
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    });
  });
```

blog.js

```js
const { currentPage, numPages } = pageContext;
const isFirst = currentPage === 1;
const isLast = currentPage === numPages;
const prevPage = currentPage - 1 === 1 ? '/blog' : (currentPage - 1).toString();
const nextPage = (currentPage + 1).toString();

<nav className={styles.pagination}>
  {!isFirst && (
    <Link to={`/blog/${prevPage}`} rel="prev">
      ←
    </Link>
  )}
  {Array.from({ length: numPages }, (_, i) => (
    <Link
      key={`pagination-number${i + 1}`}
      to={`/blog/${i === 0 ? '' : i + 1}`}
      activeClassName={styles.activeLink}>
      {i + 1}
    </Link>
  ))}
  {!isLast && (
    <Link to={`/blog/${nextPage}`} rel="next">
      →
    </Link>
  )}
</nav>
```

What the pagination looks like now:
[image: My pagination]

Comment: Maybe you can use [React Pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate) library

Comment: You could have a function to create a list of pages to show. It would take the amount of pages and decide if all are sent or just some... In case there are more than 5 (or X), you could use currentPage to find the middle and set your pages that way. Then check if there's a gap in numbering between 2 pages to put those three dots.